# "Optional feature not implemented" error with pyodbc query against Access database

Tags: python, ms-access, select, pyodbc, pypyodbc

To anyone that can help, thank you in advance.
I am running 64bit windows 10, 64bit office and 64bit python 3.7.2

Using pyodbc, I am trying to execute a Select statement such as this:

```
"SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = 1999"
```

In order to do this, my code is as follows:

```
existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = ?"""        
params = (1999,)
cursor.execute(existquery,params)
```

When I run this, I get the following error
    pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access 
    Driver]Optional feature not implemented  (106) (SQLBindParameter)')

I have read this might be because pyodbc has issues passing integer values, therefore I have attempted to convert to float, as this seemed to work for some people. Therefore, my code becomes:

```
existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = ?"""
params = (float(1999),)
cursor.execute(existquery,params)
```

When running this code, the program simply stops on the cursor.execute line with no error.

I have also tried using the `pypyodbc` module instead and when running the exact same code above

```
existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = ?"""
params = [1999,]
cursor.execute(existquery,params)
```

I get the following error

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

I have confirmed that there is nothing wrong with the cursor connection because the same cursor successfully runs an INSERT command.

If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update 1

Thanks for responding, I have downgraded to 4.0.24 however the error still remains, the code below will still crash out with no error

```
existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = ?"""
params = (1999,)
cursor.execute(existquery,params)
existData = cursor.fetchall()
```

Also, passing a string, doesnt work either

```
existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = ?"""
params = ('1999',)
cursor.execute(existquery,params)
existData = cursor.fetchall()
```

I have, however got it working by passing a string date such as

```
existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE ValueDate = ?"""
params = ('#01/04/1999#',)
cursor.execute(existquery,params)
existData = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, clearly this doesnt help when looking for datapoints from a specific year. It also leads to UK / US date problems as the date above is actually interpreted as the 4th January.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple string concat to build the query do? i.e. `existquery = "SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE Year(ValueDate) = " + str(1999)`

Comment: This also just stops the code and exits with no error message

Comment: What does `pyodbc.version` return?

Comment: Hi, It is version 4.0.25

Comment: I have found that running the statement

`existquery = """SELECT * FROM EconVars WHERE ValueDate = #01/05/1999#"""`

will not stall on 

`cursor.execute(existquery)`
`cursor.fetchall`

however the cursor contains -1 rows which is not correct.

Is the row count the correct way to determine if the cursor has records?

Comment: "Is the row count the correct way to determine if the cursor has records?" - No, the row count only applies to DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

Comment: Thanks, I got what I needed here by using len(cursor.fetchall)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce your issue. A change introduced in pyodbc 4.0.25 appears to cause problems with queries against an Access database when those queries use integer parameters.

The issue has been reported on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/509). In the meantime, downgrade to pyodbc 4.0.24.

#### Update

This issue was fixed in pyodbc 4.0.27.